# Use Spring Data Neo4J 3.3.0 with Grails 2.4.4 gives NullPointerException

Tags: spring, grails, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am getting in trouble since yesterday. I am trying to make SDN 3.3.0 working with Grails 2.4.4 but I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'isNotificationObserverRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
...
```

I suspect dependency conflict (maybe between something from Spring 3 ?) but I do not find anything:

here my grails dependency report

```
+--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.7
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.4.4
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.4.4
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.7.RELEASE
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.50
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.50
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.50
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.4.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:2.4.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web:2.4.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp:2.4.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-jsp:2.4.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-fileupload:2.4.4
|              \--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-common:2.4.4
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.7.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.0.7.RELEASE
|              \--- org.grails:grails-databinding:2.4.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-mvc:2.4.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-url-mappings:2.4.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-sitemesh:2.4.4
|              \--- opensymphony:sitemesh:2.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-databinding:2.4.4
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.2
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.4.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-core:2.4.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.4.4
|         \--- xalan:serializer:2.7.1
|         \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.4.4
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.4.4
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.4.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs:2.4.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-encoder:2.4.4
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.7.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-logging:2.4.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp-taglib:2.4.4
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.4.4
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.4.4
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.7.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.4.4
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.4.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-validation:2.4.4
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-async:2.4.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-async:2.4.4
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-testing:2.4.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-converters:2.4.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-test:2.4.4
|         \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:1.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-project-api:2.4.4
|              \--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.4
|                   \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.4
|              \--- jline:jline:2.12
|              \--- org.codehaus.gant:gant_groovy1.8:1.9.6
|              \--- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-domain-class:2.4.4
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.7.RELEASE
|    \--- cglib:cglib:2.2.2
|         \--- asm:asm:3.3.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-mimetypes:2.4.4
+--- org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2
+--- junit:junit:4.11
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.3.176
+--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
+--- org.grails:grails-resources:2.4.4
+--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.3.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.4.4
+--- org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.3.RELEASE
|    \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.17.1-GA
|    \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.7.RELEASE
|    \--- javax.transaction:jta:1.1
+--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.7.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.3.RELEASE
+--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:3.3.0.M1
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.7.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.0.8.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.0.7.RELEASE
|    \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.4
|    \--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.10.0.M1
|    \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-dsl:2.0.1
|    \--- org.neo4j:neo4j:2.1.5
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:2.1.5
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:2.1.5
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:2.1.5
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:2.1.5
|    \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:2.1.5
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-commons:2.1.5
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9:2.0.3
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0:2.0.3
|              \--- org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:1.1.6
|                   \--- org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.6
|              \--- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.0
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1:2.1.5
|         \--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4
+--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.3.0.M1
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.7.RELEASE
|    \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:2.1.5
|         \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:2.1.5
|         \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:1.1.1
|    \--- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:2.1.5
|    \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:1.9.7
|         \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.7
|    \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.7
|    \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.9
|         \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.9
+--- org.neo4j:neo4j-spatial:0.13-neo4j-2.1.2
|    \--- org.geotools:gt-main:9.2
|         \--- org.geotools:gt-api:9.2
|         \--- com.vividsolutions:jts:1.13
|         \--- jdom:jdom:1.0
|         \--- javax.media:jai_core:1.1.3
|    \--- org.geotools:gt-shapefile:9.2
|         \--- org.geotools:gt-data:9.2
|         \--- org.geotools:gt-referencing:9.2
|              \--- java3d:vecmath:1.3.2
|              \--- commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
|              \--- org.geotools:gt-metadata:9.2
|                   \--- org.geotools:gt-opengis:9.2
|                        \--- net.java.dev.jsr-275:jsr-275:1.0-beta-2
|              \--- jgridshift:jgridshift:1.0
|    \--- org.geotools:gt-process:9.2
|         \--- org.geotools:gt-coverage:9.2
|              \--- it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-tiff:1.1.7
|                   \--- it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-utilities:1.1.7
|                   \--- javax.media:jai_codec:1.1.3
|              \--- org.jaitools:jt-zonalstats:1.3.0
|              \--- org.jaitools:jt-utils:1.3.0
|         \--- org.geotools:gt-cql:9.2
|         \--- javax.media:jai_imageio:1.1
|    \--- org.geotools:gt-render:9.2
|    \--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2
|    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
+--- org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:4.2
+--- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:1.3.2
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.9.0
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:4.9.0
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:4.9.0
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:4.9.0
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:4.9.0
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:4.9.0
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:4.9.0
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:4.9.0
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:4.9.0
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:4.9.0
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:4.9.0
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:4.9.0
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:4.9.0
|         \--- com.spatial4j:spatial4j:0.4.1
|    \--- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.5
|    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:4.1
|    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:4.1
+--- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-client-groovy:0.10.0
+--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
+--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3
+--- com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.4
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.0
|    \--- joda-time:joda-time:2.4
+--- org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1
|    \--- org.multiverse:multiverse-core:0.7.0
|    \--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
+--- org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.1.2
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.8
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:1.9.9
|    \--- org.mozilla:rhino:1.7R4
|    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2
+--- org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.6.1
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.1.Final
|         \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
|         \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.0.0
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.6.Final
|         \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final
|              \--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final
|              \--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|              \--- org.jboss:jandex:1.1.0.Final
|    \--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8
|    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.0.GA
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.1.3.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:3.1.3.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.7.RELEASE
|         \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.4.Final
|              \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|         \--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.4.0
|    \--- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:2.0.5
+--- org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.9
+--- org.grails.plugins:mongodb:3.0.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb:3.0.1.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.4.1.RELEASE
|         \--- com.gmongo:gmongo:1.2
|         \--- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.12.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.1.0.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-web:3.1.0.RELEASE
+--- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0-RC4
|    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.3.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.3.RELEASE
+--- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:1.4.0.M3
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:cors:1.1.6
|    \--- net.spy:spymemcached:2.10.3
|    \--- com.google.guava:guava-io:r03
|         \--- com.google.guava:guava-annotations:r03
|         \--- com.google.guava:guava-base:r03
|    \--- org.pac4j:pac4j-core:1.5.0
|    \--- org.pac4j:pac4j-oauth:1.5.0
|         \--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1
|         \--- org.scribe:scribe:1.3.5
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.0.6
+--- org.grails.plugins:redis:1.6.3
|    \--- redis.clients:jedis:2.6.0
|         \--- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.0
+--- org.grails.plugins:gson:1.1.4
+--- org.grails.plugins:aws-sdk:1.7.11
|    \--- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.11
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.1.1
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.1.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:mail:1.0.7
|    \--- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.1
|         \--- javax.activation:activation:1.1
|    \--- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:platform-core:1.0.0
+--- org.grails.plugins:crash:1.3.0-cr7
|    \--- org.crashub:crash.cli:1.3.0-cr7
|    \--- org.crashub:crash.shell:1.3.0-cr7
|    \--- org.crashub:crash.embed.spring:1.3.0-cr7
|    \--- org.crashub:crash.connectors.ssh:1.3.0-cr7
|    \--- org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:0.11.0
|    \--- org.apache.sshd:sshd-pam:0.11.0
|    \--- net.sf.jpam:jpam:1.1
|    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.49
|    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.49
|    \--- org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.0.7
+--- org.grails.plugins:geocode:0.3
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7
|         \--- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.3
|              \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|              \--- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:1.0.6
|         \--- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.16
|              \--- xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.1
|                   \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
|         \--- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:1.2
+--- org.grails.plugins:rest-client-builder:2.0.3
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:1.0.1.RELEASE
```

Here my dependencies from BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
//        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'

        compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.3.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.3.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.7.RELEASE'
        test 'org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.3.RELEASE'

//        compile "org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb:1.9"
//        compile "org.neo4j:neo4j:2.0.2"

        compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:3.3.0.M1'
        compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.3.0.M1'

        compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-spatial:0.13-neo4j-2.1.2'

        // Workaround to resolve dependency issue with aws-java-sdk and http-builder (dependent on httpcore:4.0)
        build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2'
        build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2'
        runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2'
        runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2'

        compile 'org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:4.2'

        compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:1.3.2'
        compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-client-groovy:0.10.0'

        // used by CacheService
        compile "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"

        compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3'

        compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.4'

        compile "org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.9"

//        compile ":gson:1.1.4"

        compile ":mongodb:3.0.1"

        compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
        compile ":spring-security-rest:1.4.0.M3", {
            excludes: 'spring-security-core'
        }

        compile ":redis:1.6.3"

        compile 'org.grails.plugins:gson:1.1.4'

        //here go your plugin dependencies
        runtime ':aws-sdk:1.7.11'

        compile ":mail:1.0.7"

        // grails events
        compile ":platform-core:1.0.0"

        compile ":crash:1.3.0-cr7"

        compile ":geocode:0.3"

        compile ":rest-client-builder:2.0.3"
    }
```

And my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd">

    <bean id="grailsApplication" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean">
        <description>Grails application factory bean</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pluginManager" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean">
        <description>A bean that manages Grails plugins</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml"/>
        <property name="application" ref="grailsApplication"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsConfigurator" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="grailsApplication"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="pluginManager" ref="pluginManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="characterEncodingFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter">
        <property name="encoding">
            <value>utf-8</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" base-package="my.application.dao"/>
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="my.application.dao"/>

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase">
        <constructor-arg value="http://neo4j:7474/db/data/" index="0"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Note that if I am switching back to the version that I used (3.0.2.RELEASE) it's working fine. Neo4J Server is in v2.1.6.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Up guys :) Nobody has an idea of this ?